# Is it possible to close all the current tabs in a single shortcut command in Sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Command Ctrl + W can close one single tab , but there is some way to close them all ? Or some way to configure that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option in the File menu `Close All Files` which will do what you wish. If you want to [bind it to a keyboard shortcut](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html), open your user key bindings from the Preferences menu, and add the following:

```js
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "close_all" }
```

Once you save the file, you can now close all tabs with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>.

The keybindings file is in [JSON](http://json.org) format, so all the commands are surrounded by an opening square bracket `[` on the first line, and a closing bracket `]` on the last line. If there are multiple entries, each entry should have a comma `,` at the end, except for the last entry. `//` single-line comments and `/* ... */` multi-line comments are also allowed.